# Pandas: Summing every element in another column corresponding to a given category except itself

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas dataframe as follows (omitting index) where 'y' and 'Category' are columns:

```
    y      Category                        
    4      A1         
    3      A2            
    1      A2               
    6      A1        
    10     A2          
    8      A1
```

I need to do the following. I need to go through each element in the 'Category' and sum all the 'y' values for that category leaving out itself and create the corresponding column. So for the above dataframe I would get the newcolumn as

```
    y    Category  Sum_except_it_self                      
    4      A1        14  
    3      A2        11    
    1      A2        13      
    6      A1        9
    10     A2        4 
    8      A1        10
```

What I am finding it difficult is to implement the 'except' itself part, when using the pandas' apply method. I need to find the corresponding value in the 'y' column when using the apply method on the 'Category' column and subtract it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let use `groupby` with lambda function and `transform`:

```
df['Sum_X_self'] = df.groupby('Category')['y'].transform(lambda x: x.sum()-x)
```

output:

```
        y Category  Sum_X_self
0   4       A1          14
1   3       A2          11
2   1       A2          13
3   6       A1          12
4  10       A2           4
5   8       A1          10
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks. Can I also use this method to find the mean value of the rest of the values? by df['Sum_X_self'] = df.groupby('Category')['y'].transform(lambda x: (x.sum()-x)/(x.count() -1))

Comment: Sure.  You can calculate that using that sum()-x divided by x.size -1.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot